# react native error app has not been registered

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I get the following error after i tried to run the app with headless js task . I made sure no other instances of packager are running and the require files are at the proper locations as well.

> Application rectNDemo2 has not been registered.
>   The Error can also happen due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistery.registerComponent.

index.js

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

var rtask = require('./randomTask');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('rectNDemo2', () => App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('randomTask', () => rtask);
```

[image]

It runs fine when the randomTask lines are commented out. Is there any other proper way to register headlessTask or to using require().The randomTask.js is in the same folder as index.js.

randomTask.js

```js
module.exports = async (taskData) => {

    console.log('service initiated!');

      setTimeout(() => {
    
        fetch('http://luxorea.com/android.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    

      }, 20000);

  };
```

Comment: Can you try with `var rtask = require('./randomTask').default;`?

Comment: didn't work, throws the same error.

Comment: It runs fine when the randomTask lines are commented out. Is there any other proper way to register headlessTask or to using require().The randomTask.js is in the same folder as index.js.

Comment: Can you share the content of `randomTask.js`?

Comment: shared it above.